# How do I revert back to official Linksys firmware from dd-wrt on WRT56G2 v1?

Tags: dd-wrt, firmware, wrt54g

I've been [having trouble with dd-wrt on my Linksys WRT56G2 v1 router](https://superuser.com/q/399902/117307) and want to go back to the [stock Linksys firmware](http://homedownloads.cisco.com/downloads/firmware/FW_WRT54G2V1_1.0.04.005_US.bin) for it.  The router has only 2MB of flash memory, and so I'm running the 'micro' version of dd-wrt.

My question is what is the best way to do that?

- I could use the http://router/Upgrade.asp dd-wrt "firmware upgrade" web interface to do it, in which case there's a dropdown menu choice for "After flashing, reset to": "don't reset" or "reset to default settings".  Which should I pick?
- [Some people](http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1430732.htm#post5422667) say that I should use a program called `tftp.exe` instead.  I can probably gain access to a Windows machine if this is necessary.

Which of these is the way to proceed?  I don't want to brick the router if at all possible!

Note: I used the 'wrt54g' tag because I wasn't allowed to create a 'wrt54g2' tag due my low rep here.

Comment: Someone made a comment that started "Reset removes all settings entirely. The CFE (the", but it has since been deleted.  I think because it was attached to an answer from David that he has since deleted.  Care to repost it?  That's all I can see of the comment in the email alert.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [Linksys e1000 v2](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/e1000), that was flashed with the `dd-wrt.v24-21061_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini_e1000v2.bin` firmware. The wireless performance was horrible.

I have tried various settings, looks like I didn't try changing interference mitigation settings, but anyways, I reverted back to the Cisco/Linksys `FW_E1000_2.1.03.005_US_20140321.bin` firmware through the upgrade firmware DD-WRT web GUI with reset to factory defaults after update selected. Then did one more factory reset by holding the button on the back and it worked.

Before, wireless performance was 0.3 Mbps 2 ft away or through two walls (apartment built in the 80's) 20 ft away. Now I'm getting 10 Mbps through the same two walls 20 ft away.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction here http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G2#Reverting_back_to_stock_Linksys_firmware

Not so easy, so be careful not to brick it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading over the web using dd-wrt expects a dd-wrt sysupgrade image. An image file from linksys there will brick your router for good.

Comment: Where are you getting this from? Do you have a cite?

Comment: I've done it several times and it has always worked. Also, it's impossible to brick your router for good just by changing the user firmware. You can always recover so long as the CFE isn't corrupted.